# Copy user permission to another user in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: permissions

I am looking for a PowerShell script which could copy a user permission to another user in SharePoint 2010? Do we also have any script which will additionally perform the actions like - Transfer user permissions, - Remove user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the best thing to do would be to put the users in the same group and assign the permissions to the group.

It's the item (Web, List, List Item, etc.) that keeps track of who has permissions more so than the user keeping track of what items it can access, so to do what you want in a way that works if permission inheritance is broken anywhere would be tricky.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however due to our complex security guideline, we may need to give the permission to individuals on the folders, files...which becomes more complex to manage as well as it needs longer time and effort to copy/transfer/revoke the permissions..